# Is it always true that "max $\ge$ average + sigma"?

Tags: inequality, average

Assume that $i$ from $1,\ldots,N$, $x_i \ge 0$ and:

$$\mathrm{avg} = \frac{\sum_i x_i}{N}$$

$$\sigma = \sqrt\frac{\sum_i{(x_i-\mathrm{avg})^2}}{N}$$

Is that true that:

$$\max_i x_i \ge \mathrm{avg} + \sigma\text{ ??}$$

**REFERENCE**

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In fact it's not even true when you replace sigma by the square root of sigma i.e. the standard deviation rather than the variance.

As an example, consider the set of numbers {0,6,6}

Mean: 4

Variance:8

Standard Deviation: 2.83

Comment: Does variance == 8/3??

Comment: No. I have a feeling you haven't squared the deviations in your calculation.

Comment: I think you forget to divide to number of items. $sigma=\sqrt{8/3}$ so 6 > 4 + 1.6

Comment: Re terminology, sigma is often the standard deviation rather than the variance.

Comment: Mean is $\frac{0+6+6}{3}=\frac{12}{3}=4$. Then $sigma=\frac{(0-4)^2+(6-4)^2+(6-4)^2}{3}=\frac{4^2+2^2+2^2}{3}=\frac{16+4+4}{3}=\frac{24}{3}=8$

Comment: now that you've edited to include the square root, we have $sigma=\sqrt{8}=2.83$

Comment: It is true that at least *one* of $min$ or $max$ is at least one $\sigma$ away from the average; but which one it is depends on the actual set of values you have.

Comment: No problem at all.